# How to handle responsive bootstrap 3 tables with large content?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a Wordpress plugin that uses a Bootstrap 3 responsive table, but the content of the table data cells in each row are larger than just a couple words.

There are **three** columns with `item`, `description`, and then an image of the product.

When the smaller device media query is crossed and the table becomes responsive the `nowrap` element causes the table collapses into single lines of text and scroll forever.

I thought maybe removing the `nowrap` would solve the issue, but that just stops the table from being responsive.  Are there any elegant solutions for multi-line content in a responsive table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check this site might be it help for you.[Responsive tables](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)